# PHP flatten array with duplicate values

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to flatten an array so that duplicates are removed and unique values are retained.  For example:

```
$places = array( 
   array("United Kingdom","London","Camden","1"), 
   array("United Kingdom","London","Camden","5"),
   array("United Kingdom","London","Camden","23"),
   array("United Kingdom","London","Camden","71") 
);
```

Would become:

```
$places = array("United Kingdom","London","Camden","1,5,23,71");
```

or

```
$places = array('Country' => 'United Kingdom',
                'County' => 'London',
                'City' => 'Camden',
                'Codes' => array(1,5,23,71)
          );
```

Comment: To whoever marked me down for the question, it would be nice to know where I went wrong with it so I know for the future.

Comment: Not my downvote, but this question has at least two issues: a) no proof of an attempt to solve the problem on your part and b) not phrased in a way that is going to make it useful to others.

Comment: Fair enough.  But its hard for a beginner to explain.  I'll be sure to put in my failed attempts to solve it next time.  Cheers Jon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since all the values in your array items are strings you can use them as part of an array key for convenience. So this is a possible solution:

```
$temp = array();
foreach($places as $items) {
    $id = array_pop($items);
    $key = serialize($items);
    $temp[$key][] = $id;
}

$result = array();
foreach($temp as $k => $ids) {
    $result[] = array_merge(unserialize($k), array($ids));
}
```

It does favor convenience over efficiency, but it's pretty short.

**[See it in action](http://ideone.com/4BhaVe)**.

Answer (score 1):

In three steps:

- Firstly gather information by indexes
- Then use `array_unique` for unique values
- Finally join the three arrays in big one.

**Code**

```
$places = array( 
   array("United Kingdom","London","Camden","1"), 
   array("United Kingdom","London","Camden","5"),
   array("United Kingdom","London","Camden","23"),
   array("United Kingdom","London","Camden","71") 
);

foreach ($places as $p) {
   for ($i=0; $i<count($p); $i++) {
        $t[$i][]=$p[$i];  
    }
}

for ($i=0; $i<count($t); $i++) {
    $new[$i]= implode(",", array_unique($t[$i]));
}

$result=array_merge($new);
```

**Example**

```
print_r($result);

Array ( [0] => United Kingdom [1] => London [2] => Camden [3] => 1,5,23,71 )
```

Comment: How is `array_unique` going to help here? It compares values as *strings*.

Comment: It does help. See I firstly suggest to get an array for every column.

Comment: Thanks, fedorqui.  Nice to receive a few different approaches to the solution.  I plan to go through each one and figure out how it all works :)

Comment: Sure, @iltdev! It is an issue that can be done on quite different ways. So here you have two.

Answer (score 0):

```
$places = array( 
   array("United Kingdom","London","Camden","1"), 
   array("United Kingdom","London","Camden","5"),
   array("United Kingdom","London","Camden","23"),
   array("United Kingdom","London","Camden","71") 
);

$result = array();
foreach($places as $val){
   $result['Country'][$val[0]]  = $val[0];
   $result['County'][$val[1]]  = $val[1];
   $result['City'][$val[2]]  = $val[2];
   $result['Codes'][$val[3]]  = $val[3];
}
$final   = array();
foreach($result as $key=>$value){
    $final[$key]  = implode(",",$value);
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r($final);
```

Output :

```
Array
(
    [Country] => United Kingdom
    [County] => London
    [City] => Camden
    [Codes] => 1,5,23,71
)
```

Answer (score -1):

Use array_unique() like for eg:

```
 $places = array( 
 array("United Kingdom","London","Camden","1"), 
 array("United Kingdom","London","Camden","5"),
 array("United Kingdom","London","Camden","23"),
 array("United Kingdom","London","Camden","71") 
 );

echo "<pre>";
print_r(array_unique($places));

o/p


Array
(
   [0] => Array
    (
        [0] => United Kingdom
        [1] => London
        [2] => Camden
        [3] => 1
    )
)
```

hope will help it!